# Child theme, how to cut the functions.php file into several classes?

Tags: functions, child-theme, oop

The `functions.php` file of my **Child Theme** is a mess...
I'd like to use classes in a separate folder (like /inc) but I would like to keep a maximum of security.
For now everything works as excepted, but is my code safe enough to use in production ?

- `functions.php`

  ```
  // Include our classes.  
  require_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/inc/class.my-class-1.php' );  
  require_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/inc/class.my-class-2.php' );  
  ...  

  // Instantiate our classes.  
  $my_class_1 = new My_Class_1();  
  $my_class_2 = new My_Class_2();  

  // Hooks goes here.  
  add_action( 'hook_i_want', array( $my_class_1, 'my_function_in_class_1'), 10 );  
  add_filter( 'other_hook_i_want', array( $my_class_2, 'my_function_in_class_2' ) );  
  ...
  ```

Or maybe a better idea ?

Comment: I don't see what using classes has to do with security?

Comment: I copy-paste some code I found after hours of digging and luckily it works as expected but i'm still far away from understand what I'm doing.